# Output of Azure Peerings

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I'm currently working on a script that gives me the output of every Peering in an Azure Subscription, with both VNets listed and some options like AllowVirtualNetworkAccess, AllowForwardedTraffic, UseRemoteGateways, and AllowGatewayTransit. The output should look something like this:

```
Peering Name     VNet 1          VNet 2          AllowVirtualNetworkAccess AllowForwardedTraffic UseRemoteGateways AllowGatewayTransit                                    
------------     ------          ------          ------------------------- --------------------- ----------------- -------------------
test-peering     vnet-ine-test   vnet-chn-docker False                     True                  False             False
vnet-docker-test vnet-chn-docker vnet-ine-test   True                      True                  False             False
```

This is what my script currently looks like:

```
$VNets = Get-AzVirtualNetwork
$peerings=@()
$peeringInfo = @{ "Peering Name"="" ; "VNet 1"="" ; "VNet 2"="" ; "AllowVirtualNetworkAccess"="" ; "AllowForwardedTraffic"="" ; "UseRemoteGateways"="" ; "AllowGatewayTransit"=""}
foreach($VNet in $VNets){
   $peeringInfo.'Peering Name'=$VNet.VirtualNetworkPeerings.Name
   $peeringInfo.'AllowVirtualNetworkAccess'=$VNet.VirtualNetworkPeerings.Name
   $peeringInfo.'AllowForwardedTraffic'=$VNet.VirtualNetworkPeerings.Name
   $peeringInfo.'UseRemoteGateways'=$VNet.VirtualNetworkPeerings.Name
   $peeringInfo.'AllowGatewayTransit'=$VNet.VirtualNetworkPeerings.Name
   $peering = Get-AzVirtualNetworkPeering -VirtualNetworkName $VNet.Name -ResourceGroupName $VNet.ResourceGroupName
   foreach($peer in $peering){
        $peeringInfo.'VNet 1' =$peer.VirtualNetworkName
        $peeringInfo.'VNet 2' =(Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $peer.RemoteVirtualNetwork.Id).Name
        $obj=New-Object PSObject -Property $peeringInfo
        $peerings +=$obj
   }

  
}
$peerings | Format-Table "Peering Name","VNet 1","VNet 2",AllowVirtualNetworkAccess,AllowForwardedTraffic,UseRemoteGateways,AllowGatewayTransit
```

And this is the output:

```
Peering Name     VNet 1          VNet 2                           AllowVirtualNetworkAccess AllowForwardedTraffic UseRemoteGateways AllowGatewayTransit
------------     ------          ------                           ------------------------- --------------------- ----------------- -------------------
test-peering     vnet-ine-test   {vnet-ine-test, vnet-chn-docker} test-peering              test-peering          test-peering      test-peering       
vnet-docker-test vnet-chn-docker {vnet-ine-test, vnet-chn-docker} vnet-docker-test          vnet-docker-test      vnet-docker-test  vnet-docker-test
```

I know that the problem has to do something with the line `$peeringInfo.'VNet 2' =(Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $peer.RemoteVirtualNetwork.Id).Name`, because when I just run `(Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $peer.RemoteVirtualNetwork.Id).Name` there are two outputs, which is weird because the
$peer.RemoteVirtualNetwork.Id should only be one value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer. It was in fact the line `$peeringInfo.'VNet 2' =(Get-AzVirtualNetwork | Where-Object ID -EQ $peer.RemoteVirtualNetwork.Id).Name`. It has now been changed to Where-Object, to compare the ID, instead of searching for the name. Here is the full script:

```
$VNets = Get-AzVirtualNetwork
$peerings=@()
$peeringInfo = @{ "Peering Name"="" ; "VNet 1"="" ; "VNet 2"="" ; "AllowVirtualNetworkAccess"="" ; "AllowForwardedTraffic"="" ; "UseRemoteGateways"="" ; "AllowGatewayTransit"=""}
foreach($VNet in $VNets){
    $peeringInfo.'Peering Name'=$VNet.VirtualNetworkPeerings.Name
    $peeringInfo.'AllowVirtualNetworkAccess'=$VNet.VirtualNetworkPeerings.AllowVirtualNetworkAccess
    $peeringInfo.'AllowForwardedTraffic'=$VNet.VirtualNetworkPeerings.AllowForwardedTraffic
    $peeringInfo.'UseRemoteGateways'=$VNet.VirtualNetworkPeerings.UseRemoteGateways
    $peeringInfo.'AllowGatewayTransit'=$VNet.VirtualNetworkPeerings.AllowGatewayTransit
    $peering = Get-AzVirtualNetworkPeering -VirtualNetworkName $VNet.Name -ResourceGroupName $VNet.ResourceGroupName
    foreach($peer in $peering){
        $peeringInfo.'VNet 1' =$peer.VirtualNetworkName
        $peeringInfo.'VNet 2' =(Get-AzVirtualNetwork | Where-Object ID -EQ $peer.RemoteVirtualNetwork.Id).Name
        $obj=New-Object PSObject -Property $peeringInfo
        $peerings +=$obj
   }

  
}
$peerings | Format-Table "Peering Name","VNet 1","VNet 2",AllowVirtualNetworkAccess,AllowForwardedTraffic,UseRemoteGateways,AllowGatewayTransit
```

And here is the output:

```
Peering Name     VNet 1          VNet 2          AllowVirtualNetworkAccess AllowForwardedTraffic UseRemoteGateways AllowGatewayTransit
------------     ------          ------          ------------------------- --------------------- ----------------- -------------------
test-peering     vnet-ine-test   vnet-chn-docker                     False                  True             False               False
vnet-docker-test vnet-chn-docker vnet-ine-test                        True                  True             False               False
```